# Best way to create email database for multiple users

Tags: c#, mysql, email

So here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm building an app using c# and MySQL as it's database. The database should basically be able to store inbox, sent mail, drafts, spam and trash typically.

Now here's the issue. This app is supposed to support multiple users. Meaning each user is supposed to see their own email's. Typically this would suggest that I must create a new schema for every new user, anme it accordingly and create tables inside it for inbox, sent, drafts etc.

Yes, it would be possible I suppose but assuming I may have a thousand user's... That's gonna make database management tedious among other issues that may arise.

Question here is would there be a more organised way / method of doing this? Preferably one that would make management or coding for it easier.

Appologies to be so broad. This is for a school project.

Comment: why not the same schema for all users?

Comment: Well yeah but.... How does each user see their own emails if they are all in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This app is supposed to support multiple users.

That basically means you need a table `Users` and every table supporting multiple users needs a column where you store the `Users` `Primary Key`. That way you can have a single table and have the data of multiple users in it.

Comment: So I can filter them according to users in the app right? Trying this out. Will update shortly.